# Best protocol for embedded PIC microcontroller to communicate with server over the internet?

Tags: networking, snmp, network-protocols, tcp, microchip

Firstly, thank you for taking the time out to read this post.

I'm looking to develope a TCP/IP enabled device using the Microchip PIC18 or PIC32 family of embedded microcontrollers with Microchip's TCP/IP Stack. However, my knowledge of networking is pretty basic at the moment, thus the reason for this post.

Can anyone recommend the best protocol to use for my TPC/IP embedded device so that it can communicate with a server in a data centre? My intention is to have the embedded device located at a remote location somewhere over the internet, where the server can communicate with the device and download data such as thermometer probe readings to be stored in a database. I would also like the ability for the server in the data centre to be able to reconfigure settings and variables on the remote device should I need to.

My research on protocols so far has lead me to the following options:

- SNMP v3 (version 3 due to encryption and authentication)
- UDP (though I read this can be unreliable but is fast)
- TCP (I'm not too clued up on this yet)

Can anyone offer me advice on the best route to go down? I'm not expecting a detailed answer from you, but I would really like an idea of what topics/protocols to look into and research.

My intent is to deploy many of these embedded devices over the internet where they all send their data back to the server.

I assume that the remote embedded device will have to connect to the server rather than vice versa as the server will have a static IP address or DNS name, whereas the remote device addresses will be unknown.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciate. Please don't hesitate to ask if I've missed out any key information in this post.

Many thanks.

Rob

* UPDATE ***
It was pointed out that I'm probably misusing the term Web Server, so I've amended my post to mention Server in a Data Centre instead. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Comment: How do you mean communicate exactly? I might just use SMTP if the requirements allowed it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ElliottFrisch . Well I intend to have a server in a data centre, and remote TCP/IP enabled device located in remote locations over the internet. Some how I need to get the data that is logged on the remote devices to the database on the server in the data centre. So my question is, what's the best method to securely transfer data from the remote devices to the server in the data centre?

Comment: I've used UDP. It's low-level and doesn't require a lot of burden on the PIC. It sounds like your server will ping the PIC. I don't see a problem sending a UDP packet from server to the PIC and have the PIC respond to the command in the packet with another UDP message back to the server. If the server doesn't get a response in period of time, resend the command.

Comment: Best will require you to determine what your requirements are more precisely; however, you should consider a TLS secured protocol (like https) or ssh. I would not recommend you attempt to write your own protocol unless you're prepared to learn some incredibly esoteric math. Like elliptic curves and/or the generation of extremely large pseudo-primes.

Comment: Thanks for posting here @kenny. It looks like UDP could be a route for me to go down. Someone else also commented on it on another forum. Maybe you can help clear something up for me though. For the server to ping the PIC, wouldn't it need to know its IP addresses? What if the address is unknown? Wouldn't the PIC have the send data to the server rather than the server request the data since the server address is the known factor? or am I getting the wrong end of the stick about how this works?

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. I certainly don't intend to create my own protocol. I want to know what the best standard protocol would be for me to use and research when wanting to send and receive data between a server and many remote devices over the internet. For example many TCP/IP enabled temperature logging devices feeding data to a server.

Comment: HTTPS over TCP is the route I would go. What if the PIC is behind a firewall?

Comment: I would say you're correct with your understanding. Generally, servers can't/shouldn't rely on clients to be online or always available at the same address. Only once a client establishes a secure connection with the server should their communication be trusted. Is this a problem?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I guess the admin will have to unblock the firewall port if it becomes and issue :). I'm just trying to work out what the best and most secure method for application would be. I'm a complete newbie to networking so I'm trying to work out my head from my tail at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Alfie. Once a connection is established from the client to the server then everything should be fine. I assume with TCP/IP once a connection is made then data can be received and transmitted from both the server and the client? For example the server could request data as well as the client automatically sending data??

Comment: @RobHurd I would have the PIC send a registration command over UDP to the server if it doesn't get pinged. The registration would have the PIC's IP address.

Comment: Thanks @kenny. I will certainly look into how UDP works.

Comment: Yes that is basically all true. However, this may not always be true depending on protocol specs. For instance, with HTTP the client can specify whether the connection should be persistent (or not). If it is not, the connection is closed as soon as the initial transaction is completed (the server won't wait around for more data). While you are sure the client is connected, you can send/receive whatever you like between them; how you validate this is the key. Confirmation messages to server/client requests help maintain the client/server relationship too

Comment: Maybe HTTP is the best route for me to look into. I would like the sever to also check that the device is online/available as a way to ensure it's online and communicating successfully.

Comment: You should only really use HTTP if you want the data to be accepted by an /actual/ web (HTTP) server or viewed in a browser. I don't think this is what you need. With regards to the online availability, I would suggest making the clients poll/ping the server on a regular basis - if that time is exceeded, the server can assume the client is no longer available (effectively it's no different to a TCP or UDP timeout)

Comment: Thanks @Alfie. Really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

If the target is a Web server you don't have any choice. You have to use HTTP, which runs over TCP.

Or else you are misusing the term 'Web server'.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. So is SNMP just a local network protocol and cannot be used over the internet?

Comment: Sorry, all I mean by web server is simply a server in a data centre connected to the internet setup with a static IP / DNS.

Comment: Whether SNMP can be used depends entirely on whether the relevant UDP ports (161-2) are open all the way between the peers. Same applies to all other protocols actually.

Answer (score 1):

In many ways this depends on your specific requirements. TCP/IP is able to provide quite reliable connections because it provides a means to determine if the client is connected, when they connected and when they disconnected. UDP is connectionless, so the server opens a port and listens for data, but has no automatic connection management, so clients need to explicitly 'tell' the server when they have arrived or are going (this also means you will need to make your own timeout facility).

Also, if you have very limited memory/processing resources, it is worth bearing in mind that UDP is a less 'costly' protocol as it avoids a lot of the overheads TCP incurs due to its inbuilt connection management.

While these are all protocols, they really just handle the connections themselves. You will probably still need to create your own protocol for the management of the data itself. For instance, when you send data over either TCP or UDP, the bytes you send may not all arrive to the server at the same time. This means you need a way of validating each packet you receive to ensure you have it all. This is often achieved with a combination of a checksum and a byte representing the total size of the data sent.

Comment: Thank you for response @Alfie. I will read up some more about sending and receiving TCP and UDP data. The trouble I'm having is that I'm completely new to networking, so I'm trying to figure out my head from my tail with this.

Comment: Without knowing a more about exactly what it is you are doing, it is difficult to suggest the best strategy, but to help clarify regarding the protocols: you can consider HTTP as a 'data transfer protocol'; it defines the rules about the port used, the format data needs to be sent in, and what it needs to include (such as the length of the data or the character encoding used). However, HTTP uses TCP [the connection protocol]. FTP uses TCP (port 21), as does POP/SMTP (etc etc.), but these are all their own protocols too. UDP is commonly used with online games or when efficiency is paramount .

Comment: Thanks @Alfie. I think I need to read up on HTTP as a data transfer protocol, plus all of the others mentioned. I simply want to design an embedded device that logs temperature readings, their time stamps and a unique ID to identify the device at a remote location, then send the data securely over the internet to a server to be stored in a database.

Comment: I wouldn't really bother with that, unless it's just to see how a few existing protocols work. HTTP will more than likely be way overkill for what you need. When working out your protocol, you need to start with looking at the maximum potential complexity. If your 'packets' are small and fixed, this is very easy. Say for example you sent the temp and timestamp in a consistent format, with the starting character of `$`: `$001.002013-12-23` (where the temp is always in format XXX.XXX), your server would just need to listen for packets 17 bytes long that started with `$`.

Comment: I see what you're saying @Alfie. Just did a quick search for sending data over HTTP. I'm assuming sending data over http is this GET & POST methods? an example I found is here <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data>

Comment: Yep that's the one :) HTTP packets use ~250 bytes just describing the data they contain. Usually this is way more than you want a PIC to have to deal with. If you can get away with TCP, I would prefer that option. If you need /very/ real-time updates or are transferring data very quickly, UDP is probably better. If you can't guarantee your data will always be in a simple format or if you need more flexibility, take a look at the popular fletcher checksum (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher's_checksum). With this I would start all packets with a unique character followed by packet length..

Comment: ..then you could make the next 3 characters be a command identifier, and separate other parameters with a line feed (char 10), then include the checksum as the final char. Just an idea, but hopefully gives you a better view of how to structure your own transport proto

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider mqtt (http://mqtt.org). It is a lightweight messaging protocol. For encoding your messages, you might consider protobuf (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)